# Polymer-starter-kit: my-app.html missing from bundled build folder

Tags: build, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit, polymer-cli

I am using the polymer-starter kit for my app and tried building it. When opening the index.html of the builded app the my-app.html is missing. I didn't change any files in the starter kit, and the problem also appears.

**Steps to Reproduce**

Create an application project: polymer init --> select polymer-starter-kit
Build: polymer build
Try viewing index.html

**This is what I get in the console:**

/src/my-app.html Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

webcomponents-loader.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the current origin ('null') is not supported.

/images/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: You can check your ```polymer.json``` file in the root directory to see what fragments are being built.  More info here: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-json

Comment: are you opening index.html directly by double clicking it.

Comment: are you open index.html directly? try use `polymer serve` on your working directory